# Animate a view containing subviews with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, autolayout

This is the setup:

- A UIView created on Interface Builder, linked to an IBOutlet variable (`_vAbout`)
- A constraint for this view that we want to animate, linked to an IBOutlet variable (`_ctrBottomAboutView`)

I am using this code to animate:

```
_ctrBottomAboutView.constant = -100;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [_vAbout layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

My problem is: **whenever the view has any subviews in it, the animation doesn't work**. However, if the view has no children, the animation works correctly.

Do you have any idea of a solution? I have tried everything: adding and removing constraints instead of modificating the constant value, adding constraints to the subviews on Interface Builder...

Comment: Have you tried changing the .constant inside the animations block?

Comment: Yes, it has the same behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some experiments starting from the ground with an empty project, this is what I've found:

Given A the view we want to animate and B its superview

- It's very important to keep in mind that the view that receives the `layoutIfNeeded` message is **the view that owns the constraint**.
- In the case of `NSLayoutAttributeWidth` and `NSLayoutAttributeHeight` the owner of the constraint is actually A, but in all the other cases, the view that owns the constraint is B

HOWEVER

- If A does not have any subviews, we can call `[A layoutIfNeeded]` at any time on our code and it will work
- If A has one or more subviews but we start the animation on `viewDidLoad` we can call `[A layoutIfNeeded]` and it will work